# How can I add a point to a relative position on a canvas graph?

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph

I have a bit of code (involving "canvas"), which generates a graph on a four-quadrant cartesian plane. (Please see the JsFiddle link in the comment below.)

I want to create a bit of code that adds a point to a specific position on the plane. However, I want the point to get plotted based on the intervals on the x- & y-axes rather than pixels. In other words, I don't want to have to guess and check where each coordinate is on the graph and then adjust accordingly. If I move the graph 200 pixels down on the page, I want the point to likewise move 200 pixels down.

Coding novice, here (if you couldn't tell already). It took me forever to get to this point, so I would greatly appreciate any help anyone is willing to offer.

Thanks!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/huj7csta/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2D canvas context provides a transformation to all rendering.

You can set the matrix with `ctx.setTransform` and you can multiply the existing transformation with `ctx.transform`, `ctx.scale`, `ctx.rotate`, `ctx.translate`

Personally I am a big fan of `ctx.setTransform(a,b,c,d,e,f);`  where

- a,b is the unit length and direction of the X axis in pixels
- c,d is the unit length and direction of the Y axis in pixels
- e,f is the location of the origin relative to the top left and is in
  pixels.

Basicly 2 vectors defining the size (scale) and direction of a pixel x and y axis, and a coordinate defining where on the canvas the origin is. The coordinate is not effected by the scale or rotation.

So if you want the X axis to point down and the scale to be two then 
`a = 0`, `b = 2` the Y axis is then `b = -2`, `c = 0` to be 90deg clockwise from the X axis.

If you want the axis to remain the same but the scale `scale = 2` changed then
`a = scale`,`b = 0`, `c= 0`, `d = scale`. And to have the origin at the center of the canvas `e = canvas.width/2`, `f = canvas.height/2`

Now if you draw an arc `ctx.arc(0,0,100,0,Math.PI*2)`  you will see a circle in the center of the canvas with a `radius =  100*scale`

Hope that makes sense....

Comment: Thank you so much for that detailed write-up! Much appreciated. Like I said, I'm a newbie, so to synthesize that, can I just add the following to the end of the script: " `ctx.setTransform(0,2,-2,0,canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);`
  `ctx.arc(0,0,100,0,Math.PI*2)"` or do I have to precede that by defining each of the variables, a - f? (I included the code at the end of this script, as best as I understood [link] https://jsfiddle.net/huj7csta/5/)

Comment: You have got it right. Just a note that the transformation remains active until you change it. The default transformation (identity matrix) is `setTransform(1, 0, 0 , 1, 0, 0)` If you are familiar with matrices you will notice that there are only 6 values, while a 2D transform requires 9, The missing 3 are always 0,0,1. To help you out the best referance is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ this is the landing page. What they cant supply can be found in the many references.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason the point isn't showing up on my JsFiddle...at the risk of being a pain, would you mind glancing at the end of my JsFiddle code to see what I did wrong? (I inserted the code for the point right before the final </script> tag.)

Comment: You forgot to add the draw call. Put `ctx.fill()` or `ctx.stroke()` after arc to see the result. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help...and your patience :)